# Allow unsubscribing from moderator elections

Tags: feature-request, notifications, election

I get notifications of elections from every single community I've joined, even if it is just for a single question and I have no interest in the community whatsoever. I know that they don't come super often, but it is still annoying, since I see the badge on my inbox and think "Ooh, a new message, I wonder what it is?", but then disappointment that it was just a reminder for an election I'm not at all interested in.